# Debian: Cron bash script every 5 minutes and lftp

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, cron

We have to run a script every 5 minutes for downloading data from an FTP server. We have arranged the FTP script, but now we want to download automatic every 5 minutes the data.

We can use: "0   *   *   *   * /home/kbroeren/import.ch"
where import the ftp script is for downloading the data files.

The point is, the data files become every 5 minutes available on the FTP server. Sometimes this where will be a minute offset. It would be nice to download the files when they become a couple of seconds be available on the FTP server. Maybe a function that scans the ftp file folder if the file is allready available, and then download the file, if not... the script will retry it again in about 10 seconds.

One other point to fix is the time of the FTP script. there are 12k files in the map. We should only the newest every time we run the script. Now scanning the folder takes about 3 minutes time thats way too long. The filename of all the datafiles contains date and time, is there a possibility to make a dynamic filename to download the right file every 5 minutes ?

Lot os questions, i hope someone could help me out with this!

Thank you
Kevin Broeren

Our FTP script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 HOST='ftp.mysite.com'
 USER='****'
 PASS='****'
 SOURCEFOLDER='/'
 TARGETFOLDER='/home/kbroeren/datafiles'

 lftp -f "
 open $HOST
 user $USER $PASS
 LCD $SOURCEFOLDER
 mirror --newer-than=now-1day --use-cache $SOURCEFOLDER $TARGETFOLDER
 bye
 "

 find /home/kbroeren/datafiles/* -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you might want to give a try to [curlftpfs](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/curlftpfs). Using this FUSE filesystem you can mount an FTP share into your local filesystem. If you do so, you won't have to download the files from FTP and you can iterate over the files as if they were local. You can give it a try following these steps:

```
# Install curlftpfs
apt-get install curlftpfs
# Make sure FUSE kernel module is loaded
modprobe fuse    
# Mount the FTP Directory to your datafiles directory
curlftpfs USER:PASS@ftp.mysite.com /home/kbroeren/datafiles -o allow_other,disable_eprt
```

You are now able to process these files as you wish. You'll always have the most recent files in this directory. But be aware of the fact, that this is not a copy of the files. You are working directly on the FTP server. For example removing a file from /home/kbroeren/datafiles will remove it from the FTP server.

If this works foor you, you might want to write this information into /etc/fstab, to make sure the directory is mounted with each start of the mashine:

```
curlftpfs#USER:PASS@ftp.mysite.com /home/kbroeren/datafiles fuse auto,user,uid=USERID,allow_other,_netdev 0 0
```

Make sure to change USERID to match the UID of the user who needs access to this files.